# Vertical bar for each tbody inside a table

Tags: html, css, html-table, pseudo-element

I've a dynamic HTML page which has a table with multiple 'tbody' elements.
Now, I'm stuck with CSS as I need to show a vertical bar inside each of the 'tbody' as shown in the image attached.

How could I get this done? I tried using 'tr::after' and creating a bar, but didn't help.

Here's my html:

Could you please help me achieve this?

```html
<table>
  <tbody class="container">
    <tr>
     <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
     <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>   
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="container">
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>   
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="container">
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>   
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: UI Design]

Comment: Please paste the CSS you have tried.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @connor
This does the trick:

```css
tbody {
         margin: 10px;
         display: block;
        }
```

```html
<style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td:first-child {
        border-right: 1px solid #000;
    }
    tbody {
     margin: 10px;
     display: block;
    }
</style>
<table>
 <tbody class="container">
  <tr>
   <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
   <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
   <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody class="container">
  <tr>
   <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
   <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
   <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody class="container">
  <tr>
   <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
   <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
   <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try giving the `:first-child` `td` a `border-right`. If you're gonna have multiple columns, in stead of 2, try using `:not(:last-child)` in stead of `:first-child`.

```html
<style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td:first-child {
        border-right: 1px solid #000;
    }
</style>
<table>
 <tbody class="container">
  <tr>
   <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
   <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
   <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody class="container">
  <tr>
   <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
   <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
   <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody class="container">
  <tr>
   <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
   <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
   <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but if you compare it with the design I'm looking for a uniform single vertical line.

Comment: I've added a css rule to the `table` selector, it's `border-collapse: collapse;`. This makes the line uniform.

Comment: Thanks, but still it doesn't match the design. I meant to have one signle verticle bar for each of the tbody element. But, at the moment we've one for all of them.